# How to return with a specific status in a Python Google Cloud Function

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I notice that I can raise or return, producing 500 or 200 responses. for example:

```
def random(request):
    coin = [true, false]
    if random.choice(coin):
        succeed()
    else:
        fail()

def succeed():
    return '{ "status": "success!"}'

def fail():
    raise Exception("failure")
```

something roughly like that will produce either a 500 or a 200 response. But it doesn't, for example, let me raise a 422 error with a body.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Under the hood, Cloud Functions is just using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), so you can return anything that you can return from a Flask endpoint.

You can just return a body and a status code together like this:

```
def random(request):
    ...
    return "Can't process this entity", 422
```

Or, you can return a full-fledged Flask [`Response` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#response-objects):

```
import flask

def random(request):
    ...
    return flask.Response(status=422)
```